# Ошибки при запуске на хосте

Tags: python, бот

Есть бот для твича, который ходит по каналам, собирает баллы, ставит ставки баллами каналами и тд. На домашнем пк все отлично работает. Решил залить на хостинг, склонил проект, запускаю файл нужный [image: 1]

Вот такие ошибки при запуске на хосте. Почему на пк все работает правильно, а на хосте не может найти импорты? Вся структура папок сохранены, все файлы на месте.

Comment: А копировали только файл и все? Он ругается что у вас не установлены модули.

Comment: Используете ли виртуальное окружение? Достаточно легко перетащить все общедоступные модули с одного места в другое

Comment: @Kers все файлы которые были на пк, сначала на гитхаб залил, а потом клонировал оттуда на хост

Comment: @Дмитрий впервые занимаюсь размещением чего то на хостинг поэтому ничего сказать точно не смогу, потому что не знаю.

Comment: Виртуальное окружение врятли перенесется простым копированием. На компе где запускаете скрипт и он работает сделайте `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, а на хостинге `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Так вы установите на сервере те же пакеты что есть на ПК (может и лишние но не думаю что это важно).

Comment: @Kers установил все модули из requirements.txt, запускаю файл, получаю то же самое

Comment: Тогда сложнее уже... надо смотреть где python ищет модули есть ли они там, делать везде через виртуальное окружение и перетаскивать все через него.  Потому что  ругается он что не видит модуль...